# Typescript update items within object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have this object:

```
info: {
   firstName: Joe,
   lastName: Smith,
   userName: jsmith
}
```

Then through a function I want to update just the userName within info because his `userName` is now `jsmith1`. How would I go about doing such a thing?

Comment: just do info.userName=jsmith1

Answer (score 1):

`info.userName = "jsmith1";`

or...

`info["userName"] = "jsmith1";`

If you are interested in understanding JavaScript objects, [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4968448/7081471) also provides an explanation of when to use bracket notation vs. dot notation